# Sphinx and filtering by sql_attr_str2ordinal

Tags: sphinx

I don't sure it's my problem or problem in bin-release (I use Win64 binaries w/MySQL support    2.0.6-release). The problem in the fact that i have incorrect searching result when I find and sort by sql_attr_str2ordinal field. Below I attached dump with searching example.( For example i search "test" find 7 results, then I want sorted by leng_id, and key 0 is worked, but another key 1 and 2 does not work . 
From dump I think you can understand problem). 
Dump:

```
c:\server\sphinx\bin>search.exe -a test
Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file './sphinx.conf'...
index 'topicsIndex': query 'test ': returned 7 matches of 7 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=18, weight=2602, topic_date_add=Tue Oct 30 01:16:19 2012, topic_publ
ish=1, topic_lang=1, tag=(19)
2. document=1, weight=2577, topic_date_add=Sun Sep 30 14:32:05 2012, topic_publi
sh=1, topic_lang=1, tag=(2)
c:\server\sphinx\bin>search.exe -a test
Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file './sphinx.conf'...
index 'topicsIndex': query 'test ': returned 7 matches of 7 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=18, weight=2602, topic_date_add=Tue Oct 30 01:16:19 2012, topic_publ
ish=1, topic_lang=1, tag=(19)
2. document=1, weight=2577, topic_date_add=Sun Sep 30 14:32:05 2012, topic_publi
sh=1, topic_lang=1, tag=(2)
3. document=19, weight=2577, topic_date_add=Tue Oct 30 01:17:24 2012, topic_publ
ish=1, topic_lang=2, tag=(20)
4. document=20, weight=2577, topic_date_add=Tue Oct 30 02:11:30 2012, topic_publ
ish=1, topic_lang=1, tag=(21)
5. document=3, weight=1556, topic_date_add=Sun Sep 30 15:54:52 2012, topic_publi
sh=1, topic_lang=2, tag=(4)
6. document=4, weight=1556, topic_date_add=Mon Oct 01 00:48:09 2012, topic_publi
sh=1, topic_lang=0, tag=(5)
7. document=17, weight=1556, topic_date_add=Tue Oct 30 00:17:39 2012, topic_publ
ish=1, topic_lang=0, tag=(18)

words:
1. 'test': 7 documents, 15 hits

index 'commentsIndex': query 'test ': returned 3 matches of 3 total in 0.000 sec


displaying matches:
1. document=242, weight=1646, comment_date=Wed Oct 31 01:40:51 2012, comment_del
ete=0, comment_topic_lang=1
2. document=1, weight=1606, comment_date=Sun Sep 30 22:55:56 2012, comment_delet
e=0, comment_topic_lang=1
3. document=241, weight=1606, comment_date=Tue Oct 30 02:11:46 2012, comment_del
ete=0, comment_topic_lang=1

words:
1. 'test': 3 documents, 4 hits


c:\server\sphinx\bin>search.exe -a test -f topic_lang 0
Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file './sphinx.conf'...
index 'topicsIndex': query 'test ': returned 2 matches of 2 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=4, weight=1556, topic_date_add=Mon Oct 01 00:48:09 2012, topic_publi
sh=1, topic_lang=0, tag=(5)
2. document=17, weight=1556, topic_date_add=Tue Oct 30 00:17:39 2012, topic_publ
ish=1, topic_lang=0, tag=(18)

words:
1. 'test': 7 documents, 15 hits

index 'commentsIndex': search error: .

c:\server\sphinx\bin>search.exe -a test -f topic_lang 1
Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file './sphinx.conf'...
index 'topicsIndex': query 'test ': returned 0 matches of 0 total in 0.000 sec

words:
1. 'test': 7 documents, 15 hits

index 'commentsIndex': search error: .

c:\server\sphinx\bin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql_attr_str2ordinal is not for filtering , just for sorting.
Also use the sql interface or api rather than search tool ( it's more for testing).

Comment: But the query "search.exe -a test -f topic_lang 0" giving me only elements where topic_lang=0. Like a first query I do "search.exe -a test -f topic_lang 1" but don't get topics with topic_lang=1. but I know about existing of this topics (you can see this in query "search.exe -a test")

Comment: use an integer field to encode the lang or sql_field_string ( you can do fulltext match (eg. @topic_lang en) on it and also sorting )

Comment: Don't understand about integer field, sql_field_string also not give me result. Could you explain more detail. And I want ask about sql_attr_str2ordinal, if this parameter only for sorting, why "search.exe -a test -f topic_lang 0" give me only 2 results from 10. Thanks

Comment: Forget about search tool. Use either the API or the SphinxQL interface :). That search tool was made more for testing and is pretty much a 'second class citizen'.  Why you want to use sql_attr_str2ordinal ? It's a sorting only field, shouldn't be used for filtering.

Comment: I using existing code and sphinx configuration with sql_attr_str2ordinal. In DB topic_lang is a text like 'english', but I need filtering by id. And it is unclear, some indexes works when others do not. (This not work in search tool and PHP API)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I done this with CRC32 and uint attribute